# Problem with sending the response back to JS from PHP

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I want to send to a mail with a click on the HTML. I used ajax to call a PHP file. I included the PHP mailer code to send an email. And I also include a print json_encode("Success") at the bottom. I couldn't send the success message from php back to JS. I have used Print and many other output commands in PHP its not working.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"api/collect_money.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:ajax_data,
    async:false,
    success:function(response)
    {
        console.log(response,"hello");
    }
});
```

This is my PHP:

```
function sendmail($bills_count_data)
{
    //print_r($bills_count_data[0]['end_date']);
    //Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'php/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'php/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'php/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try 
    {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = '****@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '****';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
        // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('****@gmail.com');    

        //$mail->addAddress('****@thewashhouseinc.com');           // Name is optional
        // $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
        //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
        //Attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Collect Money Notification';
        $mail->Body    = "Collection has been made on ".$bills_count_data[0]['end_date']." The list of bills: one's ".$bills_count_data[0]['one']." two's ".$bills_count_data[0]['two']."";

        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
        $mail->send();
        //echo 'Message has been sent';
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}

sendmail($bills_count_data);
}

print ("success");
```

I don't see any response on the console. when I execute this code

Comment: i've edited your question, don't show us your email password!!

Comment: Don't know if that's the issue, but you got one more bracket in your php than is needed. Try removing closing bracket after sendmail($bills_count_data);  }

Comment: The PHP code has a `}` too many. Open up your browsers development tools and open the network-tab. Make another request and check what response you're actually getting from the server.

Comment: How are you defining `$bills_count_data`?

Comment: I posted full php code below.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be your problem:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

That outputs all kinds of stuff that's not remotely like JSON, and will cause your parsing of the response to fail. If you look at the raw response in your browser's dev tools, you should see it all. Disable debug output with:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
```

Comment: I did change the SMTPDebug=false. But still, I am not able to see the response from php.

Comment: Hey Synchro, Its working. I had a small bug in my mysql query. Thats causing problem and your solution helped me remove the unwanted response from the phpmailer. Thank you so much.